# Get process owner from AD

Tags: powershell

I am using Powershell on Windows Server 2008 R2 and I need any regular user get owner of the process with name and surname from AD.

Here's script wrote with help of **Mathias R. Jessen**

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ProcessWithOwners = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter 'Name LIKE "vr[0-9]%"' |Select *,@{Name="Owner";Expression={$_.GetOwner().User}}
 foreach($Process in $ProcessWithOwners)
 {
    $Username = $Process.Owner 
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Username'" -properties *
    $a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
    $b = $a.popup(“Process name $($Process.Name) is run by user $($ADUser.DisplayName)“,0,“Warning”,1)
 }
```

But regular user can't get access to process's owner.

Is there any way to solve it?

*** Final Update ***

For running this script as regular user I made some changes:

```js
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
 
Add-Type -Name win -MemberDefinition '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(int handle, int state);' -Namespace native
[native.win]::ShowWindow(([System.Diagnostics.Process]::GetCurrentProcess() | Get-Process).MainWindowHandle,0)
 
$ConsProcess = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter 'Name LIKE "vr[0-9]%"' | Select *,@{Name="Owner";Expression={$_.GetOwner().User}}
 
if ($ConsProcess -ne $null) {
 foreach($Process in $ConsProcess)
 {

$QueryProcess = query process $Process.ProcessName
$Id = ($QueryProcess[1] -replace ' +',' ').Trim().Split(' ')[2]
$QueryUser = query session $Id
$User = ($QueryUser[1] -replace ' +',' ').Trim().Split(' ')[1]
$ADUser = (Get-ADUser -Identity $User -Properties *).DisplayName

$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell
$b = $a.popup(“Консультант запущен с именем $($Process.Name) пользователем $($ADUser)“,0,“Внимание”,1)
 }
}

else
{
& 'D:\consultantplus\cons.exe' /adm /inet
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot about it)) The problem is that Out-String returns array and last  Write-Host returns empty string...

Comment: `$(Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$user'").DisplayName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to call both `gwmi Win32_Process` *and* `Get-Process` when all you need is just the Owner.

You can do with just:

```
$CmdProcessWithOwners = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter 'Name LIKE "cmd%"' |Select *,@{Name="Owner";Expression={$_.GetOwner()}}
```

Since you could potentially find more than one process matching your criteria, you might want to iterate over the process(es) in a loop:

```
foreach($Process in $CmdProcessWithOwners)
{
    # Grab the user name we added earlier
    $Username = $Process.Owner.User
    $Domain = $Process.Owner.Domain

    $DisplayName = switch($Domain)
    {
        'DOMAINNAME' {
            # Process owned by AD User, grab name from AD
            Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$Username'" -Properties DisplayName |Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName
        }
        $env:ComputerName {
            # Process owned by local user, look up local account full name
            [adsi]"WinNT://$($env:ComputerName)/$Username,user" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
        }
        default {
            # Likely system or virtual account, default to DOMAIN\Username
            "$Domain\$Username"
        }
    }

    # Print it
    Write-Host "Process $($Process.Name) with ID $($Process.Id) belongs to $DisplayName"
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much! Also there should be "-properties *" in Get-ADuser

Comment: @user3301252 Just make sure you are doing `-Properties DisplayName` and not `*`. You don't use all of the properties. You just need the one you dont get by default.

Comment: Be careful, as a process owner might be a local account--in this case, Get-ADUser will return (at best) nothing or (at worst) an incorrect account name (in the case where the local user name matches a domain user name).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart (somewhat) taken care of now

Comment: Can this script run normal user, not Admin?

Comment: @user3301252 No, in that case it'll only return accurate owner information for processes belonging to the user in question